# Why is my AVX2 2D convolution as slow as my scalar implementation?

Tags: c, optimization, x86, convolution, avx2

I tried optimizing my 2D convolution function using AVX2 but I'm not getting any speedup compared to my scalar implementation.

On an input matrix of 8192*8192 with the `iterations` parameter (parameter only used for benchmarking) set to 10, I'm getting 750ms on average on both the scalar and SIMD implementation.

I compiled the code using g++ with -O3 and -march=native.

I profiled the SIMD code with Intel VTune and most of the time is spent in `_mm256_add_pd`, `_mm256_mul_pd` and the `for (line_x_idx)` loop , not even loads / stores so I'm confused as to why the SIMD implementation is as slow as the scalar implementation

Here is the scalar code:

```
void kernel(int iterations, int N, double in_mat[N][N], double out_mat[N][N], double conv_mask[3][3])
{  
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        for (int mat_y_idx = 1; mat_y_idx < N - 1; ++mat_y_idx)
        {
            for (int mat_x_idx = 1; mat_x_idx < N - 1; ++mat_x_idx)
            {
                double convolve_value_0_0 = in_mat[mat_y_idx - 1][mat_x_idx - 1] * conv_mask[0][0];
                double convolve_value_0_1 = in_mat[mat_y_idx - 1][mat_x_idx + 0] * conv_mask[0][1];
                double convolve_value_0_2 = in_mat[mat_y_idx - 1][mat_x_idx + 1] * conv_mask[0][2];

                double convolve_value_1_0 = in_mat[mat_y_idx + 0][mat_x_idx - 1] * conv_mask[1][0];
                double convolve_value_1_1 = in_mat[mat_y_idx + 0][mat_x_idx + 0] * conv_mask[1][1];
                double convolve_value_1_2 = in_mat[mat_y_idx + 0][mat_x_idx + 1] * conv_mask[1][2];

                double convolve_value_2_0 = in_mat[mat_y_idx + 1][mat_x_idx - 1] * conv_mask[2][0];
                double convolve_value_2_1 = in_mat[mat_y_idx + 1][mat_x_idx + 0] * conv_mask[2][1];
                double convolve_value_2_2 = in_mat[mat_y_idx + 1][mat_x_idx + 1] * conv_mask[2][2];

                double sum = 0.0;

                sum += convolve_value_0_0;
                sum += convolve_value_0_1;
                sum += convolve_value_0_2;

                sum += convolve_value_1_0;
                sum += convolve_value_1_1;
                sum += convolve_value_1_2;

                sum += convolve_value_2_0;
                sum += convolve_value_2_1;
                sum += convolve_value_2_2;

                out_mat[mat_y_idx][mat_x_idx] = sum;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my SIMD implementation:

```
void kernel(int iterations, int N, double in_mat[N][N], double out_mat[N][N], double conv_mask[3][3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        for (int mat_y_idx = 1; mat_y_idx < N - 1; ++mat_y_idx)
        {
            int line_x_idx;
            for (line_x_idx = 1; line_x_idx < N - 1 - 4; line_x_idx += 4)
            {
                __m256d sum_0 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
                __m256d sum_1 = _mm256_setzero_pd();
                __m256d sum_2 = _mm256_setzero_pd();

                //Unrolled by the compiler when compiled with optimizations
                for (int kernel_index = -1; kernel_index <= 1; kernel_index++)
                {
                    __m256d in_values_0 = _mm256_loadu_pd(in_mat[mat_y_idx - 1] + line_x_idx + kernel_index);
                    __m256d in_values_1 = _mm256_loadu_pd(in_mat[mat_y_idx + 0] + line_x_idx + kernel_index);
                    __m256d in_values_2 = _mm256_loadu_pd(in_mat[mat_y_idx + 1] + line_x_idx + kernel_index);

                    sum_0 = _mm256_add_pd(sum_0, _mm256_mul_pd(in_values_0, _mm256_set1_pd(conv_mask[0][kernel_index + 1])));
                    sum_1 = _mm256_add_pd(sum_1, _mm256_mul_pd(in_values_1, _mm256_set1_pd(conv_mask[1][kernel_index + 1])));
                    sum_2 = _mm256_add_pd(sum_2, _mm256_mul_pd(in_values_2, _mm256_set1_pd(conv_mask[2][kernel_index + 1])));
                }

                _mm256_storeu_pd(out_mat[mat_y_idx] + line_x_idx, _mm256_add_pd(sum_0, _mm256_add_pd(sum_1, sum_2)));
            }

            //Leftover elements
            if (line_x_idx != N - 1)
            {
                for (; line_x_idx < N - 1; line_x_idx++)
                {
                    double sum = 0;

                    for (int kernel_index = -1; kernel_index <= 1; kernel_index++)
                    {
                        sum += in_mat[mat_y_idx - 1][line_x_idx + kernel_index] * conv_mask_premult[0][kernel_index + 1];
                        sum += in_mat[mat_y_idx + 0][line_x_idx + kernel_index] * conv_mask_premult[1][kernel_index + 1];
                        sum += in_mat[mat_y_idx + 1][line_x_idx + kernel_index] * conv_mask_premult[2][kernel_index + 1];
                    }

                    out_mat[mat_y_idx][line_x_idx] = sum;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What CPU?  Have you profiled cache misses?  It could be a memory-bandwidth bottleneck.  Math instructions that have to wait for a slow load result get the "blame" for the time spent, if you profile events like `cycles` (`cpu_clk_unhalted.thread`).

Comment: I assume GCC is optimizing your mul+add into FMA instructions?  You aren't actually using any AVX2 intrinsics, just AVX1, but `-march=native` on modern CPUs will include FMA.  And GCC defaults to `-ffp-contract=fast` IIRC, so it will contract across statements, including for intrinsics.  But I'd have written it with `_mm256_fma_pd` for better throughput, fewer back-end uops.

Comment: GCC is able to auto-vectorize your scalar code (and it does fuse mul+add to FMA): https://godbolt.org/z/EKf14f8Kd

Comment: I'm on an i7 6700k @PeterCordes. I've ran a cachegrind on my program and it reports 12.3% D1 miss rate and 6.3% LLd msis rate. Is it high? I have no reference to compare that against. But 1/16 reference completely missing and going to the RAM seems high(?). Compiled with `-march=native` (and by looking at the assmelby with `-S`), gcc doesn't fuse mul+add into `fmadd`but compiling with `-march=skylake`does use `fmadd` (thanks to @chtz for pointing out auto-vectorization which I had completely forgot).

Comment: 6.3% LLC miss rate normally only counts misses as a fraction of LLC accesses (L2 misses), not as a fraction of total loads.  The `mem_load_retired.l3_miss` counts total load instructions that miss in L3.  But anyway, the fact that your scalar version auto-vectorizes decently explains why your intrinsics version isn't faster.  (Using multiple accumulators (sum_0..2) to hide FP latency apparently wasn't necessary for such a short chain of FMAs; Skylake's out-of-order exec window is big enough to hide it.)

Comment: What GCC version are you using where `-march=native` is different from `-march=skylake` on a Skylake CPU?  Perhaps some old GCC version too old to know about Skylake? But then it wouldn't recognize `-march=skylake`.  Maybe you forgot to enable optimization for one of them?

Comment: I'm using GCC 11.3.0. I checked again and made sure to compile with -O3 in both cases: `gcc -O3 -march=native -fverbose-asm -S convolution.c` (or `-march=skylake`), the `-march=native` still doesn't use `fmadds`. Looking at the "options passed" comment at the top of the `-march=native`  compiled `.s` file, I can see `-mno-fma` there. Why is that?

Comment: Didn't see your reply since you didn't `@PeterCordes` notify me.  Are you sure you (or some IDE?) didn't add any other command-line options?  `-march=haswell` or `-march=skylake` definitely does use `vfmadd231pd` in chtz's Godbolt link, as in https://godbolt.org/z/qssxzenaf.  If your CPU is a Skylake Pentium or Celeron, then it won't have AVX or FMA support.  Were you maybe seeing `-mno-fma4`?  FMA4 is an AMD Bulldozer (and Zen 1) extension, separate from FMA3 (`-mfma`) which Intel didn't tell AMD about until the last minute, to sabotage their chips.

Comment: @PeterCordes I compiled it on the commandline, I made sure to only use `-O3 -march=native -fverbose-asm -S`. It is the `-march=native` option that doesn't use FMADD instructions. If I compile with `-march=skylake`, FMADD are used. Could this be because I'm compiling on an Ubuntu virtual machine and not a native system?

Comment: If your VM is (mis)configured to not expose the FMA3 feature bit via CPUID, then yeah, GCC `-march=native` won't use it.  It won't fault as long as your VM exposes at least AVX; the OS only needs to see the AVX feature bit to enable YMM instructions to not fault, and know to save/restore the YMM registers on context switches.